# Import with access to context (nunjucks)

Tags: nunjucks

In my app.js, I have this :`app.locals.testvalue = "lolo"`

In my macro.html, I have this : `{% macro powertestvalue(x) %} <p> {{ x }} : {{ testvalue }}</p>{% endmacro %}`

The problem is I can only user the powertestvalue macro in "macro.html" because of the following :

1. If I use "include", I won't be able to use the powertestvalue from the file which includes macro.html .
2. If I use "import", macro.html won't access the global scope, and won't be able to use {{ testvalue }}.

How should I deal with this issue ?

Comment: It's even worse than expected. I can access a macro which is defined in the parent, but not in the parent of the parent.

Answer (score 0):

You might find this useful: http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#import-context-behavior

Try:

```
{% from 'macro.html' import powertestvalue with context %}
```